# Can polymorhpic_on be used over more than one column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table (and I am not allowed to change it's schema) which contains rows that are represented by three classes.

The values in columns `a` and `b` determine which class corresponds to a row.

```
if row.a == 'X': return X
elif row.b == 'Y': return Y
else: return Z
```

Obviously there is not good column for `__polymorhpic_on__`.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`polymorphic_on`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=polymorphic_on#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.polymorphic_on) can be a column *or SQL expression*, so you just need to figure out an appropriate expression that will return an identity value.

In this case, the expression can be a case statement returning constants that will identify the subclasses.  `a == 'X'` maps to `1`, `b == 'Y'` to `2`, etc.  Note that the expression doesn't return an instance, it produces a SQL expression used for mapping the eventual instance.

```
case(((a == 'X', 1), (b == 'Y', 2)), else_=3)
```

The following is a full runnable example of this solution.  The case statement has been modified to use `literal_column`s.  It's more verbose, but doesn't require sending 4 bind params each time.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
session = Session(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class ThreeWay(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'three_way'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = sa.Column(sa.String)
    b = sa.Column(sa.String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': sa.case(
            (
                (a == sa.literal_column("'X'"), sa.literal_column('1')),
                (b == sa.literal_column("'Y'"), sa.literal_column('2'))
            ),
            else_=sa.literal_column('3')
        )
    }


class X(ThreeWay):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 1
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['a'] = 'X'
        super(X, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Y(ThreeWay):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 2
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['b'] = 'Y'
        super(Y, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Z(ThreeWay):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 3
    }


Base.metadata.create_all()

session.add_all((X(), Y(), Z()))
session.commit()

print(session.query(ThreeWay).count())  # inserted 3 generic ThreeWay rows
print(session.query(Y).count())  # 1 of them is specifically a Y row
```